# Узнать, что процесс запущенный через WinExec завершился неудачно

Tags: c++, windows, cmd, консоль

Команда `schtasks.exe /create...` у меня вызвалась через функцию `system` и, если возникала какая - нибудь ошибка, к примеру, не было прав на создание задачи, то system возвращал 1, а вот `WinExec` возвращает 33, если задача создалась и если не создалась тоже. Не могу использовать `system`, потому что появляется консоль, а WinExec можно делать "скрытно", но вот с отловом ошибки проблема.
Как мне узнать, когда создание задачи прошло успешно а когда нет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для получения exit code используйте функцию `GetExitCodeProcess()`

Comment: WinExec не возвращает handle процесса, как мне его узнать в таком случае?

Comment: @МишаковМаксим не использовать WinExec, потому что API устаревшая. CreateProcess вернет и хэндл в том числе.

Comment: Я понял, спасибо. У меня есть одна программа, которая вызывается через WinExec, и всё вроде работает, можно в таком случае оставить как есть, или следует переписать через CreateProcess?

Comment: Работать оно и будет, пока API не выкинут совсем